# Onedrive for Business API strategy confusion (Office 365, sharepoint, Skydrive Pro)

Tags: sharepoint-2013, office365, onedrive

I am writing some Windows desktop software in C# that can access Microsoft Onedrive for Business.  This software is for anyone to use to access their own OneDrive for Business account.

Looking at the latest online documentation it seems that Azure Active Directory is needed to access the API but i have had some success without using Azure using a method similar to this (although I do have some issues):

http://jomit.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/authentication-and-authorization-with.html

My question is do I have to use Azure AD or is the above method still expected to work?

If I have to use Azure then who needs the Azure account, is it me or is it each user who will use my software?

I have downloaded other third party software that accesses my Onedrive for Business account and I did not have to do anything with Azure.  I want my software to be as simple as possible for users to connect to their Onedrive for Business account.

Answer (score 0):

If it is hosted in SP, then you do not need to do anything.
If it is hosted externally such as o365 apps, you need to register this app in Azure AD. This applies for office 365 apps or even apps that are hosted somewhere. Azure AD is important to authorize apps to use office 365, office 365 apps can be hosted anywhere.

Comment: By "it" you mean my application?  My application will be running on the Windows desktop so it's not hosted.  So far using similar code to the link I mentioned above I have been able to connect to a Onedrive for Business account, list files, download files etc.  But I am having technical difficulties with uploading.  I can upload 2 files but after that it keeps timeing out with all operations and I have to reconnect.

Comment: then you need to register the app in Azure AD. By the way, you can configure your app as a multi-tenant app which will work with all your customers.